# Something in my web site or project doesn't work. Can I just paste a link to it?

Tags: support, faq, asking-questions, question-quality

I have a CSS, HTML, or JavaScript problem on a website I'm working on.

I would like to just describe the problem and paste a link to the external site in question.  Can I do this instead of posting code on Stack Overflow - seeing as it's much easier to find my problem on the live site?

If not, why not?

[Return to FAQ index](/q/251225)

Comment: More than a handful of times, problems have been because of a server issue or configuration, unrelated to the CSS/HTML/JS.  I completely agree with the sentiment of the answers and believe folks should make a reproducible example (to hopefully find that the code isn't the problem so they can post a server question), but let's not forget there are edge cases where a link to the site can be helpful.

Answer (score 465):

No, providing a link is not sufficient. The information needed to answer the question must be provided **in the question itself**. There are several reasons for this:

1. **A linked website or code will change over time:** When you fix your website or external code repository, it will no longer demonstrate the problem and people won't be able to retrace the initial problem. This is why the code needs to be documented here on Stack Overflow, where it will be archived directly with the provided answers.

   The primary goal of Stack Overflow is to build an archive of questions and answers that are useful to people and situations *beyond* that of the person who asked the question originally. A question with just a link to code subverts this goal.
2. **It is easier to understand the problem without having to click a link:**
   Requiring users to click a link to see the code is not user-friendly. When the code is directly in the question, you will get better answers. It will also be easier for people in the future with similar problems to verify that answers apply to their situation.
3. **Code must be licensed in such a way that it can be used in answers:** Questions and answers here, including any code in them, are [licensed with creative commons](https://stackoverflow.com/legal/terms-of-service#licensing) such that they can be freely reused and modified with proper attribution. Code from an external link is unlikely to be licensed in a compatible way. Including the code in the question itself licenses it in such a way that it is allowed to be used in answers.

   The licensing issue prevents us from editing your post and fixing it for you. Unless the external code is clearly licensed with a compatible license, it would be a copyright violation for anybody but the owner of that code to include it in your question.

### Off-topic

Such a question is likely to be closed as off topic: *"This question appears to be off-topic because **it lacks sufficient information to diagnose the problem.** Describe your problem in more detail or [include a minimal reproducible example](/help/minimal-reproducible-example) in the question itself."*

### What you should do instead

Debug it! Narrow down the problem, to where you can describe it with a useful, searchable title and [a](/help/minimal-reproducible-example) *[small](/help/minimal-reproducible-example)* [bit of code](/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Don't just dump your entire page into the question — figure out which portion actually causes the problem, and include just enough code to reproduce it. Don't know how to do this? Ask!

*Then* post the code to reproduce the problem in your question, probably as a live demonstration using [Stack Snippets](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/269753/feedback-requested-runnable-code-snippets-in-questions-and-answers). As some people are more used to them, consider additionally providing it on [JS Bin](http://jsbin.com) and/ or [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/). Since these are third party services and may be unavailable at any time, **make sure your question can be understood *without* visiting these websites**.

### Debugging tips

Before you try to debug CSS or JavaScript, make sure your HTML source is **valid**. ["Broken" HTML](http://www.reddit.com/r/web_design/comments/185qvo/this_page_has_many_unclosed_h3_tags_which_leads/) is one of the most common causes of rendering and other errors, and different browsers will handle invalid HTML in different ways. Validating your HTML can reveal serious errors, like mismatched tags or duplicate `id` attributes. While not all errors are crucial to rendering (missing `alt` attributes for example), you should still fix as many of them as possible before debugging other code.

#### Validation tools

- [The W3C Markup Validation Service](http://validator.w3.org/)
- [Validator.nu (X)HTML5 Validator](http://html5.validator.nu/)
- Stack Overflow: [Validate HTML on local machine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3586207/validate-html-on-local-machine)

#### Debugging tools

- [Firefox developer tools](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Tools), for Firefox
- [Developer Tools](https://developers.google.com/chrome-developer-tools/), included in Google Chromium

A tutorial about how to use such tools: [JavaScript debugging for beginners](http://www.netmagazine.com/tutorials/javascript-debugging-beginners).

### See also

- [Questions linking to external web sites instead of showing code](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/80978/questions-linking-to-external-web-sites-instead-of-showing-code)