# Should I have any concerns on SO when asking a question with a link to production site and not being accused for spamming?

Tags: discussion

Let’s say I have a precise question that meets all SO requirements. Question is about an issue on a real, public, production website.

Sometimes it’s really faster and better to paste the link to this site than to create a fiddle that can be out of context.

Is is totally OK to ask such a question with a link to a site and not being accused about spam?

**Obviously I will paste some code snippets to "show my efforts" and attempts to solve the issue by myself.**

Basically I have an issue with my live blog where there is particular thing that behaves weird on Safari / iOS and pasting the URL for people to investigate via Chrome Dev Tools would in my opinion be the most efficient way to deal with it…

Thanks for any opinions.

Comment: Related: [Something in my web site or project doesn't work; can I just paste a link to it?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/254428)

Comment: spamming so is potentially the lesser worry when sharing a website that has problems to a group of users who could potentially know how to exploit said problems. well, lesser for you anyway.

Answer (score 22):

> Is is totally OK to ask such a question with a link to a site

No. Your code needs to go **in the question**. Questions that depend on links to external sites are off-topic.

If you can't produce a debugging question that includes everything necessary to reproduce your problem, then your question is probably not suitable for Stack Overflow.