# Is "answerable" a criteria for being "on-topic" on SO?

Tags: discussion, scope

I've recently answered [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45527641/javascript-transforming-borders-with-headers) on SO. At the time, it contained a link to the project's github test page, added as a live example featuring the problem.

Because of the added complexity, most questions on [react](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/react), [angular](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/angular), [grunt](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/grunt), [gulp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/gulp), [webpack](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/webpack), [browserify](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/browserify) and similar do not contain stack-snippets because, for the average user, setting them up is a real challenge.

For having an external link to exemplify the problem, the question was put on hold as "off-topic" on SO, at which point the OP modified the question by removing the external link, making the question "on-topic" but unanswerable. To be clear, without the ability to experience it in a live example I wouldn't have answered it in the first place, as I had no way to understand the cause. I could have ventured a guess, but that would have been wrong. In fact, I'd have simply passed.

Between an external link and no example at all, first often makes the difference between being answerable and not.

In the follow-up discussion, the user who has put the question on hold said:

> "Answerable" is not our criteria for on-topic.

...which I personally find wrong.

From where I see it, SO is a Q/A programming community. In fact, it's ***the*** Q/A programming community. I believe most rules for deciding what should and should not be asked address being answerable, even if it's not spelled out as a term.

If we apply the *"SO snippet or NO snippet"* rule without consideration on the effort to create a stack-snippet for some questions, for most of the above libraries/tools this translates to: you're not allowed to add an example.

There aren't many questions tagged `webpack` or `angular` featuring a stack-snippet. Are all these questions off-topic on SO if an external link is added?

**Note:** this becomes an issue when the question asked is CSS related (which most times requires a live example to solve) but the users asking do not know for sure their issue can be reproduced outside their build, without `react`, `angular` or `webpack`. I don't think we should punish them for making the question answerable.

Comment: Stack snippets have nothing to do with this.

Comment: @PaulCrovella, I removed the tag, even though from my point of view they do. They're not the subject, but this question involves them, their limitations and is about whether using/not using them should or should not set a question as *off-topic*. But the question is not about a snippet feature or bug, indeed.

Comment: A MCVE is required and was requested, not a stack snippet. They are not the same thing.

Comment: @PaulCrovella, from my point of view, for the question being asked, a runnable code (or live example) was needed in order to pinpoint the cause and provide an answer. In reality, the question has nothing to do with `react`, it just so happens the project is dev-ed with react and the dev wasn't able to decide whether or not that had anything to do with the issue. So they provided a link to a live test. Which, in order to help, if the question didn't feature one, I'd have asked for in order to understand the problem and help out.

Comment: Why is it critical that the example be *live*, as opposed to a [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) in the form of a Stack Snippet? (Maybe this is obvious to someone that knows more about Javascript than I do, but please consider spelling it out for people like me.)

Comment: @CodyGray live examples are critical in debugging CSS issues more than half the time. In live examples one can easily understand what rules apply what behavior and how they interact with the element. My question mostly refers to CSS related questions (which require runnable code) asked on projects built using tools/libraries which make creating stack-snippets difficult. Most users do not know for sure the problem is strictly CSS related and could be reproduced without the tool they built upon.

Comment: Isn't figuring that out part of the OP's job? That's *why* we're asked to reduce it to the minimal example.

Comment: I guess he meant ""Answerable" **alone** is not our criteria for on-topic.", because a question obviously must be answerable. But anyway you're wrong as well. Just look at the current state of the question and your answer. How the heck should that be helpful for somebody else? The question and the example code of OP isn't clear about his problem and your answer relies on his (removed) code. The same would apply when OP deletes that github repo containing the code.

Comment: @Tom, that's exactly my point. I provided the answer when the example was available and, not only it made sense, but it also solved the problem. The question was brought into an "unanswerable" state after the OP complied the "rules" and removed the example, so their question would stop being off-topic.

Comment: @jonrsharpe it may well be OP's job. But if it's too difficult for most, most won't do it. Most don't know if they'll be able to reproduce the problem outside the build tool, don't know if solving it outside the build tool will serve any purpose and they don't know if it's worth the effort. The result is: most don't do it. A few decide to provide external links to builds. Do we consider those questions off-topic for giving more info than most would in their situation?

Comment: @Tom, adding words to someone else's in order to change their meaning  doesn't seem right. It may well be what they meant, but this clarification should come from them, not from anyone else. May I ask why you're doing it?

Comment: Then most people will not get answers, and I'm very comfortable with that. There are relatively few hard requirements for a question on SO; I'd recommend spending your time on those who bother to meet them.

Comment: I see, @jonrsharpe. So you're saying that yes, most questions about projects built upon React, Angular or Webpack ***are*** off-topic on SO if they provide an external live link. Replicating inside stack-snippets is hard for most. Having an external link makes them off-topic. Not having one, makes them on-topic but harder to understand. Interesting position.

Comment: @AndreiGheorghiu if they **only** provide external links. Plunkers etc. are great as supporting information, but there should still be minimal code to recreate in the question. Plenty of other languages can't be run in the question itself, MCVEs still work just fine.

Comment: Your two comments to my comment make me wonder if you actually understood what I wrote. *"that's exactly my point."* No it isn't. Your point is that OP's first version was on-topic, but I disagreed. But I agreed with your statement that meagars comment (at least the quoted snippet) is wrong. But since he's a mod and shouldn't have such a wrong meaning of "on-topic" rules I assumed he forgot a word in his sentence (hint: the bold one) so the sentence would actually make sense.

Comment: @Tom, I haven't been clear enough: *"Exactly my point"* was: *"how the heck should that be clear for somebody else?"*. That was my initial problem: I answered a question which, at that point, made sense and was answerable, even though it made sense by using an external link. A mod came, trying to make a point but forgetting key words (good thing you remembered them, though)  the OP changed their question and all of a sudden both the question and my answer lost their ability to help anyone else, because neither made sense anymore.

Comment: The problem here is that I answered the question. Once I did, OP lost their interest. And their interest was never to help others with a similar problem, of course. I should have seen that. He was told to remove the link? No problem. Done. Anything else?

Comment: Seems to be related: [Something in my web site or project doesn't work. Can I just paste a link to it?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254428/something-in-my-web-site-or-project-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it)

Comment: *"even though it made sense by using an external link."* - and that's the issue. A question shouldn't rely on external stuff to make sense, because that "external stuff" can be gone when someone else visits the question in the future. Therefore it is ___required___ that question can stand on their own.

Comment: Tom, I just realized you're wrong and @meagar is right. What he meant is exactly what he said. Being answerable is not and should not be a criteria for declaring Q on or off-topic. Because being answerable mainly measures the question's ability to help OP. Being on-topic measures its ability to help others as well. Was the question off-topic in the first place? Yes. Has it become more on-topic after being closed as off-topic and OP complying to requests? Not really. Now it's even more so than before. Now it should be deleted.

Comment: If a question is not answerable, then it is obviously doesn't fit to Stack Overflow and is therefore not on topic. It is true that a question can also have other issues which renders it off-topic, but that doesn't change the fact that it must be answerable to be suitable here.

Comment: The point here is that setting a question as off-topic after it has an accepted answer is rarely, if ever, going to improve it. The OP will comply to anything, even if that makes question and answers nonsensical, because they already have their prize. So we should only answer questions that have the ability to help others (make sense on their own). That's what I made from this. Thank you for your replies.

Answer (score 11):

Questions that don't contain enough information inline in the post to at least verify that answer actually answers the question are off-topic. Even if  question refers to enough information to dig out for details to provide an answer via external links it does not make it on-topic.

Real minimum requirement is a bit less than true MCVE: person with some experience in the subject should be able to reconstruct/recognize the problem and confirm that answer matches  the question. Also (and maybe more important) when such person comes to the question via search they should be able to confirm that it matches their own problem. Having MCVE makes it easier, but it is often require better understanding of the topic than author of the question can provide - editing question with true MCVE after problem solved could be welcome addition.

In case you describing you can either vote to close as "typographical error/ no longer problem" or update question with MCVE or code that enough to recognize the problem. Alternatively if you believe the problem is interesting enough you can ask self-answered question explaining that particular case and link original question to you new one (consider duplicate, but may be viewed as self-promotion). In state of the post you've described it is unlikely to help any future visitors and preferably should be removed from the site. If you personally interested in providing personalized help (rather than reusable Q&A) you may consider asking posters to contact you directly or maybe solve they problems in chat instead.