# Providing a GitHub URL in questions

Tags: discussion, questions, external-links

What are the guidelines/rules for providing a link to a GitHub project when posting a question?

The reason I ask this is because there were instances where I attempted to replicate my problem in as detailed a manner as possible, but no one was able to quite solve my issue. Some people asked me to provide a link to my project so they can replicate it on their side. I've never quite seen other people do it, so I'm wondering if it is against Stack Overflow's policies. If not, what is the proper way to do this?

Comment: It might be worth showing us your question.  We could offer pinpoint advice instead of being broad.

Comment: @Makoto I can't find the specific question where someone asked me to provide a link. But it was similar to one that I posted recently https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47242503/tflearn-dnn-gives-zero-loss, it didn't get any answers until I offered a bounty, and then someone asked me if I could provide a link.

Comment: @Bolboa: The first thing that I see when opening your question is text as images.

Comment: I've added a comment to that question.  I don't mess with NumPy anymore, so I delegate any question of quality or further improvement to those that do.

Comment: Relevant: [Something in my web site or project doesn't work. Can I just paste a link to it?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/254428)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To add to Servy's answer, the main point is to make your example *minimal* enough to be able to fit in a Stack Overflow question without needing lots of external dependencies, but localized enough that it replicates your specific issue.

For example, if you stated that you had a problem with reading a file in a specific spacing format into an object in your project, the only things we'd need would be the code that reads the file into your application, what is mapping between them (if you can be specific here, that's fantastic - we don't need POJOs that are 200 LOC), and a sample file format.  We can work with you from there.

Comment: Why none of you mentioned the MCVE yet?

Comment: @user0042:  Did you miss the part where I categorically describe an MCVE?

Comment: I meant the link would be nice ...

Comment: @user0042:  I'm not sure what more value adding the link would have over describing what we're expecting.  We can get too comfortable with our variation of "duckspeak" when it comes to what we're asking for, but having the patience to simply describe what it is in more friendly terms is better, in my opinion.

Comment: Well, as additional information the link to [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) adds some more detail information how to compose, what you describe in shorter (and undoubtedly valid) terms.

Answer (score 6):

It's important that you provide enough information *in the question* to replicate the problem.  Linking to a Github isn't doing that.

Comment: Why none of you mentioned the MCVE yet?

Comment: @user0042 I did, I just didn't use that particular abbreviation.

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/359303/providing-github-url-in-questions#comment531801_359305

Comment: How about include in github link in an answer?