# Unsalvageable question is marked as "looks okay" by other reviewers

Tags: discussion, specific-question, review-audits

This question: https://stackoverflow.com/review/triage/25352856 does not seem to be asking anything. It just states that something does not work in Microsoft edge. It looks more like a bug report.

I reviewed it as "unsalvageable" but the other reviewers think it looks okay. What should happen to such a question?

Comment: A good FAQ to link to for these kinds of questions is [Something in my web site or project doesn't work. Can I just paste a link to it?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/254428/215552)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The review result notwithstanding, it should be closed.

This is not the first nor it will be the last time a one or more users review incorrectly.

You did your part on review. If you want, you can visit the question outside of review and flag for closure.

At least it was not a faulty review audit.

Comment: *"If you want, you can visit the question outside of review and flag for closure."* - And when you've done that, mod flag with a link the the review and an explaination as to how the reviewers aren't reviewing correctly - but only in cases where they're *blatantly* wrong (such as spam, or rude/abusive posts or where users are visibly *consistently* reviewing badly)

Comment: I didn't mention mod flagging because I'm not sure that we should do that every time we see a user that does not review as we think they should. Maybe if we see a _pattern_...

Comment: Updated the comment to make that more clear, you're indeed right