# Did I do something I shouldn't have done? downvotes on my post

Tags: discussion, specific-question, downvotes

I checked over my question and it seems to be pretty clear in what I'm asking. Can someone explain to me why I was downvoted? thanks

*[How can I add a semi-transparent rectangular background behind the survey form?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70206317/how-to-put-a-semi-transparent-rectangular-background-behind-the-survey-form)*

Comment: At a guess, you didn't do nearly enough research. The exact question title you used put into Google probably would've revealed the answer.

Comment: My English isn't the best. The current title isn't the one that I originally titled my post as. It was edited to the curren title.

Comment: I suspect it is because your code isn't minimal for reproducing the issue, and you didn't describe what is wrong with the code you posted, you only said what you wanted it to do. See [this help page](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Welcome to SO!  While I did vote to close your question, I did not downvote it.  However, if I were to speculate as to *why* it was downvoted, I would raise the following possibilities:

1. It duplicates at least two existing SO posts that are ≈10 years old; visitors to the question might have felt you should be able to find an answer from research instead of posting a question
2. Your original post used code for complete pages, rather than a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)
3. Your original post [used offsite code examples, rather than including the code in the body of the question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254428/something-in-my-web-site-or-project-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it)
4. Your original post included a code block at the top of the question that appears to be dummy code that exists only to circumvent the site's validations that a question meet certain criteria before being posted

At a glance, these are the first things that jump to my mind as possible reasons you were downvoted.  I wouldn't take it personally-- think of it as feedback that your question was below site standards and needs some improvement.  I am sorry that you didn't get more meaningful direction as to how you could improve the post.  Hopefully this is helpful to you.  Additionally, I recommend all new users visit [How To Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask) and [take the tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) for tips on how to use the site and best enable the community to provide you with helpful assistance.  Good luck, and happy coding!

Comment: Also worth mentioning that the right hand side of the Ask Question page has guidance as well: https://i.stack.imgur.com/dFKRG.png